# Clarification needed about session cookies to access an application resource

Tags: android, header, resources, session-cookies

I am getting cookie headers as a response from a server and I need to check if they are set and if they are set, it needs to use a HTTP GET to access an application resource. (I have not mentioned params or actual URL for certain reasons. Any input for how to modify the code would be nice.

The code is:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
try {
    httppost.setParams(new BasicHttpParams().setParameter("A", "B"));
    httppost.setParams(new BasicHttpParams().setParameter("C", "D"));
    httppost.setParams(new BasicHttpParams().setParameter("E", "F"));
    httppost.setParams(new BasicHttpParams().setParameter("G", "H"));
    httppost.setParams(new BasicHttpParams().setParameter("I", "J"));
    httppost.setParams(new BasicHttpParams().setParameter("K", "L"));
    httppost.setParams(new BasicHttpParams().setParameter("M", bundle.getString("responsedata")));

    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
    httppost.setEntity(formEntity);
    HttpResponse sessionresp = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    Header[] headers = sessionresp.getAllHeaders();
    for (int i=0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        Header h = headers[i];
        Log.i(TAG, "Header names: "+h.getName());
        Log.i(TAG, "Header Value: "+h.getValue());
    }
    Log.i("sucess: ", sessionresp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"");

 // Create a local instance of cookie store

    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

    // Create local HTTP context
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/"); 

    System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

    // Pass local context as a parameter
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
```